# Angularjs complex lookup directive with dialog

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, lookup, angularjs-ng-model

I have to write an Angularjs directive that displays an input field (text) and a button. This directive should take some parameters, and should use them to lookup a record from a PgSQL database:

1. If the user clicks on the button, a $mdDialog opens and load data using a remote API call (the function to load data must be written in the controller and passed to the directive).
2. If the user fills the input field and blur it, another API call must be performed. The API must check if a record key matches the value the user has provided. If the record exists, the API must return the record from the database and fill other inputs related to other record properties. If the record does not exist, the directive must open the lookup $mdDialog, as if the user clicked on the button.

I am trying to do this, but I have some issues (I am using Material Design too).

In HTML, I have this directive (currentItem is the object loaded from the controller. showItemsLookup is the function that opens the $mdDialog):

```
<my-lookup id="art_simile" name="art_simile" size="20" maxlength="20"
           ng-model="currentItem.art_simile" data="{{currentItem}}"
           lookup="artico"
           columns="{art_simile : 'articolo',art_simile_descrizione : 'art_descrizione'}"
           error="{{showItemsLookup}}">
</my-lookup>
```

The directive code is:

```
app.directive('myLookup',['$http','$q',function($http,$q) {

    var template = `
       <span class="my-lookup">
         <input type="text" id="{{id}}" name="{{name}}"
                ngclass="(class)? class : ''" size="{{size}}"
                maxlength="{{maxlength}}" placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
                ng-readonly="readonly" ng-disabled="disabled"
                ng-model="val" ng-blur="checkLookup($event)" />
         <md-button type="button" class="md-icon-button" 
                    ng-click="{{(error)? error : null}}">
           <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-search-a" class="icon">
           </md-icon>
         </md-button>
       </span>
    `;

    return {

        restrict : 'EA',
        replace : true,
        require : 'ngModel',
        template : template,
        scope : {
            val : '=ngModel'
        },
        link : function(scope,element,attrs) {

            scope.id = attrs.id || '';

            scope.name = attrs.name || '';

            scope.class = attrs.class || '';

            scope.size = parseInt(attrs.size) || 20;

            scope.maxlength = parseInt(attrs.maxlength) || null;

            scope.placeholder = attrs.placeholder || '';

            scope.readonly = attrs.readonly || false;

            scope.disabled = attrs.disabled || false;

            scope.data = attrs.data || {};

            scope.params = attrs.params || {};

            scope.lookup = attrs.lookup || '';

            scope.columns = attrs.columns || {};

            scope.error = attrs.error || null;

            // Perform the API call.
            function _get(registry,config) {
                config = config || {};
                return $http.get(location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/apis/registry/' + registry + '/get/',config).then(function(res) {
                    return res.data;
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    return $q.reject(err.data);
                });
            }

            // Checks if the record exists or not.
            scope.checkLookup = function(event) {

                if (scope.val) {

                    var config = {id : scope.val};

                    config = angular.extend(params,config);

                    _get(scope.lookup,config).then(function(res) {
                        // The record exists.
                        angular.forEach(scope.columns,function(v,k) {
                            scope.data[k] = res[v];
                        });
                    },
                    function(err) {
                        // The record does not exist.
                        angular.forEach(scope.columns,function(v,k) {
                            scope.data[k] = null;
                        });
                        if (scope.error) scope.error(event,err);
                    });

                }

            };

         }

     };

}]);
```

I'd like to pass the entire currentItem object as the ngModel for the directive. Or, if it is not possibile (because ngModel is always a string for an input), I'd like to use another attribute (like data in the example). Attributes for this directive have the following meaning:

*data* is the object loaded from the controller.
*lookup* is the name of the API to call.
*columns* is an object that maps data keys to the lookup $mdDialog keys of each object read by the API.
*params* is an object with extra parameters to pass to the API.
*error* is the function invoked when the user fills the input and blur it, and the API finds no record key matching this value.

Issues are:

1. Angularjs Material Design display the input field as it is not empty (with the small label on top), even if ngModel is null.
2. It is possible to pass ngModel="currentItem" and display only one of its properties in the input?
3. I noticed I have to pass attributes that are not strings with interpolation (i.e.: data="{{currentItem}}"). Is there a way to pass them without interpolation, so strings must be passed with quotes? In the same way, how can
4. I pass an object like columns="{name1 : 'field1',name2 : 'field2'}"? It is automatically recognized as an object? Because if I use angular.fromJson() it gives me a JSON parse error.